# Rails - Heroku Migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I just did a migration on localhost and it worked fine. After pushing to heroku, I ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` and I get the following error stream...

```
c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in require': cannot load such file -- ffi (LoadError)
from c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/r
ubygems/custom_require.rb:36:inrequire'
from C:/Users/amoosa/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/re
stclient/windows/root_certs.rb:2:in <top (required)>'
from C:/Users/amoosa/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/re
stclient/windows.rb:7:inrequire_relative'
```

...more lines of similar errors.

How do I fix this? I'm on Windows/Ruby 2.0/Rails 4.0

I've run many migrations in the past year on this project and haven't seen this issue before.

Comment: maybe heroku looks using `Ruby 1.9` and you are `Ruby 2.0` check out that. By changing ruby version in you local if it throws similar error ?

Comment: hmm...seems like this is not just a migration issue. All heroku commands give me the same error - `heroku rollback` `heroku ps` etc.

Comment: what would changing my local version do? and it seems odd that heroku would be using an older version.

Comment: If you are using `rvm`, then install  `rvm install 1.9.3` and then use that version by `rvm use 1.9`. and try to execute local migrations.

Comment: To specifiy your ruby version on heroku, you need ruby '2.0.0' in your gemfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **think** your heroku tool-belt installation is broken.

Maybe you updated your computer or ruby version and some files were removed.

It looks like the `heroku` command is trying to load some of it's ruby files from your local directory and finds that a file it requires is missing.

the file missing is the local file referenced in line 36 of the file:
c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb

I recommend re-installing the heroku tool-belt and retrying.

I may be wrong... but that's what I read in the log.

Comment: thanks. i asked heroku support and they told me the same thing. I reinstalled toolbelt and it worked. I came back to write the answer and saw yours :-)